# Simple data reflection in meteor's template

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, handlebars.js

I'm newbie at meteor and have one big misunderstanding how templates working with data reflection.
For example I have some data in database like this:

```
{name: {firstName: "foo",
lastName: "bar"},
father: "buz"}
```

the way I can reflect it is really scary for me. I can reflect it only like this:

Js:

```
var Products = new Meteor.Collection("Products");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.DataTry.dataTryArr = function(){
     return DataTry.find({father: "buz"});
  };
}
```

html:

```
<head><title>...</title></head>
<body>{{>DataTry}}</body>
<template name="DataTry">
  {{#each dataTryArr}}
    <p>Mr. {{father}} has a son {{name.firstName}}. They are both {{name.lastName}}</p>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

It is working and reflecting. But I can not understand that `{{#each}}` and why i need `dataTryArr` in all! is is not working w/o `dataTryArr`, `{{#if dataTryArr}}`, `Template.DataTry = function(){...}` etc. in all it is not working any way w/o `{{#each}}` (what to iterate there?!)

Please, help me to understand how to reflect simple data like this way

```
<head><title>...</title></head>
<body>{{>DataTry}}</body>
<template name="DataTry">
    <p>Mr. {{father}} has a son {{name.firstName}}. They are both {{name.lastName}}</p>
</template>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm a little unclear on which part is confusing to you. The `#each` is needed when you have multiple objects coming back from the database. Were you expecting to have only one object returned by your call to `DataTry.find`?

Comment: Yeh, I expecting single object, and thought, what single object don't need iteration. Now I see the little rule if you use .find() - use {{#each}} (even though you get only single object), and if you use .findOne() - use {{#with}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use either `{{#each}}` or `{{#with}}` block helpers to iterate over the values returned from the template helpers.

If your template helper returns bunch of data from the collection, you might need the `{{#each}}` iterator, in order to render the returned values in DOM. And if the template helper returns single object, in that case `{{#with}}` block can be used.

And you have suggested this:

```
<body>{{>DataTry}}</body>
<template name="DataTry">
    <p>Mr. {{father}} has a son {{name.firstName}}. They are both {{name.lastName}}</p>
</template>
```

This will not work in any way, you shuold enclose the `<p> ... </p>` within `{{#each}}` block if the `Template.DataTry.dataTryArr()` returns array of objects.

```
<template name="DataTry">
  {{#each dataTryArr}}
    <p>Mr. {{father}} has a son {{name.firstName}}. They are both {{name.lastName}}</p>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

In simple words, `{{#each dataTryArr}}` will call the `dataTryArr` method and will iterate over the values returned.